# which Onclicklistener gives best performance and less memory leak on listView

Tags: android, performance, listview, memory-leaks, onclicklistener

I'm working with very long lists that can have 4+ views with clicks for row.

(ListView)

Method 1:

in listview public View getView()

```
vh.pprofile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){    
        JSONObject miid;
        try {
            miid = listArray.getJSONObject(position);
            MyApp.goProfile(activity, false,  miid.getString("user_id"), 1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {     }
        }
});
```

Method 2:

in ListView public View getView()

```
vh.pprofile.setTag(position);
vh.pprofile.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

In ListView class

```
MyOnClickListener onClickListener = new MyOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              if (v.getId() == vh.pprofile.getId()) {
                  JSONObject miid;
                    try {
                        miid = listArray.getJSONObject(Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString()));
                        MyApp.goProfile(activity, false, miid.getString("user_id"), 1);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {     }
              } 
       }
};
```

New Class:

```
public class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None really. What you are comparing has no difference in performance. Neither option will lead to memory leaks. A difference in performance only appears as soon as you compare creating several anonymous click listeners (option 1 multiple times) to reusing a specific click listener for different views (option 2 with switch-statement). See details in [my explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25199523/2964379).